# Basic resolve for Angular routing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, routes, resolve

I'm creating a very basic login system with Angular JS. Basically, after a login form is submitted, credentials are checked against a database using PHP and Mysqli. If all is ok, it returns successful and I set a variable like `$rootScope.isLoggedIn = true` and user details in other similar variables.

Now I'm trying to work out the best way to use `resolve` with my routes so that only logged in users or users with correct permissions can access a page (including on page reload!)

I just can't get my head around how these resolves work. My routing looks like this so far (the dashboard page needs user to be logged in):

```
app.config(function($routeProvider) {

  $routeProvider

  //login
  .when('/', {
    templateUrl : 'framework/views/login.html',
    controller  : 'LoginCtrl',
    title: 'Admin Login'
  })

  //dashboard
  .when('/dashboard', {
    templateUrl : 'framework/views/dashboard.html',
    controller  : 'DashboardCtrl',
    title: 'Dashboard',
    resolve: { ? }
  })

  //catch all redirect
  .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/' });

 });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolve will open your route with a resolved variable (that can be injected into controller) as soon as it gets value (instantly or when returned promise will be resolved). See:

```
resolve: { 
    myVar: function(service, $rootScope, etc){
        return service.obj; // or primitive, or promise or something else
    }
}
.controller('DashboardCtrl', function(myVar){
    console.log(myVar); // that service.obj goes here
}
```

That can't prevent route from loading (as I understand, please correct me if I'm wrong).

For your case it's better to use something like this:

```
.when('/', {
    templateUrl : 'framework/views/login.html',
    controller  : 'LoginCtrl',
    title: 'Admin Login',
    authenticate: false
})
.when('/dashboard', {
    templateUrl : 'framework/views/dashboard.html',
    controller  : 'DashboardCtrl',
    title: 'Dashboard',
    authenticate: true
})

$rootScope.$on("$routeChangeStart", function(event, toState){
    if (toState.authenticate && !$rootScope.isLoggedIn){
        $location.path('/');
    }
});
```

Comment: I see the logic but it isn't working for me. When I do `console.log(toState.authenticate)` I get nothing, but if I change `$stateChangeStart` to `$routeChangeStart` I do get the correct value, but the thing still doesn't work...

Comment: In fact, the route is't stopped from loading at all when the `if statement` is met. Even if I remove the `if statement` and just have `event.preventDefault();` it doesn't work.

Comment: I see. My example is for ui-router - it works great there. Quick googling reveals that native angular's $routeChangeStart can not be prevented.

Comment: Hmm. You can see the correct `toState.authenticate` value, right? Try this then: `$rootScope.$on("$routeChangeStart", function(event, toState, toParams, fromState){ if (toState.authenticate && !$rootScope.isLoggedIn){ $location.path('/'); }});`

Comment: _That can't prevent route from loading_ - It does, if the returned promise is rejected.